# How to make a Dashboard component only visible for one user in the Home Tab of an app?

Tags: dashboard, visibility

[image]

I've got this Dashboard component with some Component Visibility conditions set to it as you can see to the right:

User's first Name has to be Lauren and User's last name has to be Doster

When I log in with the System Admin profile the Dashboard component doesn't shows up because of the filters:

[image]

but then when I log in as Lauren Doster

I still can't see the Dashboard and the Home page in the App looks completely different and there is no gear icon to edit the page (I don't know if the gear icon appears when you log in as another user or not):

[image]

The question is, how can I add the component Dashboard to the Home page of the Volunteers App and make it only visible for the user Lauren Doster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the Home Page on which you have added the dashboard. You can activate it Org wide, App specific or profile level.

Refer to this documentation for more details: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_app_builder_customize_home_activate.htm&type=5